# Samba installation fails, missing directories

Tags: debian, samba

I tried installing samba on my debian server, and the installation failed with

```
$ sudo apt install samba -y

Preparing to unpack .../samba_2%3a4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba (2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1) ...
Setting up samba (2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services.
(samba-ad-dc.service masked)
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-01-24 15:08:59 CET; 20ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 30205 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/samba/update-apparmor-samba-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30214 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 30214 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 24 15:08:59 domain.not systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Jan 24 15:08:59 domain.not update-apparmor-samba-profile[30205]: grep: /etc/apparmor.d/samba/smbd-shares: No such file or directory
Jan 24 15:08:59 domain.not update-apparmor-samba-profile[30205]: diff: /etc/apparmor.d/samba/smbd-shares: No such file or directory
Jan 24 15:08:59 domain.not systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 24 15:08:59 domain.not systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 24 15:08:59 domain.not systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 installed samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While I would like to ignore the error as instructed (`Please ignore the following error`), it leaves me with not fully installed package. Never mind that, I believe this can be fixed somehow.

The problem is that the package is not working. By googling and manually running (as a root)

```
$ /usr/sbin/nmbd -S -d 1
```

I got relevant information

```
mkdir failed on directory /var/log/samba/cores: No such file or directory
Failed to create /var/log/samba/cores for user 0 with mode 0700
Unable to setup corepath for nmbd: No such file or directory
ERROR: Can't log to stdout (-S) unless daemon is in foreground (-F) or interactive (-i)
```

The `/var/log/samba` doesn't exist. So I created it and tried again, now with `-i` and got another relevant info

```
nmbd version 4.9.5-Debian started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2018
mkdir failed on directory /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock: No such file or directory
```

And again, the folder `/var/lib/samba/private` doesn't exist. At this point I questioned myself whether manually creating this folder is the right direction, as /var/lib might be mounted on some sort of temporary storage.

So basically I have two questions

- Are we (admins) supposed to manually patch installations (of well known, widely used software)?
- What did I do wrong that I am not able to install samba as every other person (I have `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (4.19.0-8-amd64)`)

Comment: The instructions refer to a _different_ error, which you did not receive. You should therefore ignore that bit.

Comment: read this https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Managing_the_Samba_AD_DC_Service_Using_Systemd

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling samba (with `apt-get remove --purge samba` and `apt-get install samba`) didn't work, but what worked was to reinstall samba-common and samba-common-bin

```
apt-get install --reinstall samba-common samba-common-bin
```